# Interactive 2D plotting in python

Tags: python, graphics, plot, chaco

I'm trying to write a program that creates a 2D grid in which the user chooses some edges between the points in the grid. Then the program dynamically manipulate those edges(eg. flip them, connect them, ...) till it converges to a particular shape.

- Now my question is there any particular module that suits this kind of interactive plotting.

So far I've looked into *PyQwt, GuiQwt, and Chaco* but cannot figure out which one is more applicable for my program. It be great if someone could compare and contrast them, or suggest new modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [PyGame](http://pygame.org/news.html) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)?

Both support 'setting pixels' on a canvas.